# Key frames don't show up in timeline nor in the dropsheet

Tags: keyframes

Can someone please explain to me why I can't see my keframes anywhere? I've been at it for hours now and I can't figure it out. [image: I've added two keyframes, one at 400 the other at 405]

Comment: You've enabled the Only Show Selected option (blue arrow icon button), have you selected the object for which you want to see the keyframes?

Comment: Yes, it's the plane I have selected on the picture. I want to make a flickering light. Enabling or disabling the Only Show Selected doesn't seem to make a difference

Comment: You need to select the node that you have keyframed. Also try to switch to Dope Sheet mode. If it still doesn't work, please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: The first Answer, Or maybe you just scrolled Away From The Section That Displays Your Keyframes .. happened to me. You can infinitely scroll in every part of Blender

Answer (score 2):

As Moonboots commented: Click here on that node "Round":

[image]

and then you will see the keyframes.

```
Note: the green background of the Value shows you that this value is keyframed.
```